# Android Black Screen on Image Click (got exception decoding bitmap)

Tags: android, bitmap

I get image on the activity by json/url into a ListView. Then I pass the image to a details_activity along with some TextViews. Now I´m trying to open the image fullscreen with Android's default gallery image viewer.

On image click a black screen is open and I get the following in logcat:

```
05-22 20:50:09.817: E/UriImage(564): got exception decoding bitmap 
05-22 20:50:09.817: E/UriImage(564): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 20:50:09.817: E/UriImage(564):    at       com.android.camera.Util.makeInputStream(Util.java:336)
05-22 20:50:09.817: E/UriImage(564):    at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:307)
05-22 20:50:09.817: E/UriImage(564):    at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:299)
05-22 20:50:09.817: E/UriImage(564):    at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:94)
05-22 20:50:09.817: E/UriImage(564):    at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:86)
05-22 20:50:09.817: E/UriImage(564):    at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.thumbBitmap(UriImage.java:120)
05-22 20:50:09.817: E/UriImage(564):    at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.executeRequest(ImageGetter.java:173)
05-22 20:50:09.817: E/UriImage(564):    at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.run(ImageGetter.java:149)
05-22 20:50:09.817: E/UriImage(564):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-22 20:50:09.876: E/UriImage(564): got exception decoding bitmap 
05-22 20:50:09.876: E/UriImage(564): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-22 20:50:09.876: E/UriImage(564):    at com.android.camera.Util.makeInputStream(Util.java:336)
05-22 20:50:09.876: E/UriImage(564):    at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:307)
05-22 20:50:09.876: E/UriImage(564):    at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:299)
05-22 20:50:09.876: E/UriImage(564):    at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:94)
05-22 20:50:09.876: E/UriImage(564):    at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.executeRequest(ImageGetter.java:204)
05-22 20:50:09.876: E/UriImage(564):    at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.run(ImageGetter.java:149)
05-22 20:50:09.876: E/UriImage(564):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

details_activity.java

```
NetworkImageView file;
String image;
private static final String TAG_FILE = "imageFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    file = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.file);

Intent i = getIntent();
image = i.getStringExtra(TAG_FILE);

ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
file.setImageUrl(image, imageLoader);

file.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + TAG_FILE), "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

THe outside activity you're using to view the image doesn't have access to that file.  Nor is your URI really calue, as it isn't a fully qualified file path to root.  The file will need to be in a folder that can be accessed by a random activity (so basically a public directory) and will need to have a full URI (easiest way to get that is to make a File object for it then convert that to a URI).

If you don't want to move the image to a public directory, you'll have to do something far more complicated like a ContentResolver.

Comment: can´t be used the same url got by json and used by the others two activities?

Comment: Possibly (depending on if the app can view a networked URL) but that itsn't what you're doing.

Comment: TAG_FILE is the url I´ve got since ListView activity. I pass it to details_activity and now to onClickListener(). Right?!

Comment: TAG_FILE is a string constant.  image is the value in the intent that was associated with that constant